# Can't find django-admin.py in Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: django, ubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu 12.10 on a new laptop, and I'm trying to get Django working. I installed it from Synaptic Package Manager, and when I try to make a sample  project on the command line, this is what I get:

```
amanda@amanda-ThinkPad-E420:~$ django-admin.py startproject caltrain
django-admin.py: command not found
```

And I verified Django is installed correctly,

```
amanda@amanda-ThinkPad-E420:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> print(django.get_version())
1.4.1
>>>
```

Is this some sorta path issue or something? I don't remember having this issue on my Mac, but again I'm not very Unix savvy to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information may be a bit stale, but I found this information that seems similar to your problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1267372

With this solution:

> Name of "django-admin.py" was changed to "django-admin" in /usr/bin directory in the python-django package.
>   To get around this I just created a symbolic link to django-admin named django-admin.py.
>   ln -s /usr/bin/django-admin /usr/bin/django-admin.py (as root)

Hope this helps, but again this was written in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

You should see this. it contains details concerning problems with django-admin.py location
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/faq/troubleshooting/#troubleshooting-django-admin-py